Display only Week view in default views on React Fullcalendar.io
I'm using Fullcalendar.io with React and I'm interested in displaying only the Week view (not a custom special one, just the default week view). Is there a way to do it without creating a custom view?

Could you provide some code samples or details on what you've tried so far?

As per the answer below, simply change the header toolbar so that none of the other view types are selectable

I saw that Fullcalendar allows for a "headerToolbar" field, in which "timeGridWeek" can be set in order that it is the only available view. That fused with the other answers here gives this:
<FullCalendar
  initialView={timeGridWeek}
  headerToolbar={
    center: "timeGridWeek",
  }
  plugins={[timeGridPlugin]}
/>


First of all not sufficient Data is given you should include the Work you've tried from your Side.
I Searched and found a code but you need timeGridPlugin from fullcalendar/timegrid library and check the below code I'm new to react dev so,
check if you can modify code anywhere

Code:

import { Calendar } from '@fullcalendar/core';
import timeGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/timegrid';

const MyCalendar = () => (
  <div>
    <FullCalendar
      plugins={[timeGridPlugin]}
      views={["timeGridWeek"]} // this line adjusts calendar to only week View 
    />
  </div>
);


If you are not using any other views at all, you can leave the views out of the header and instead set the initialView:
<FullCalendar 
initialView='timeGridDay'    
plugins={[timeGridPlugin]}         
headerToolbar={{
          left: 'prev',
          center: 'today',
          right: 'next',
        }} 
(...your other settings) 
/>

